White screen when starting google-chrome on Ubuntu 22.04
I have scoured the web for suggestions for hours.Chrome will not start. All I get is a request for a password for the ring and when I click okay a new windows appears that is all white. Just window. No menu dots, nothing.
This is  Dell optiplex 3060 mini tower with AMD RX6400 gpu. Ubuntu 22.04 w/Wayland, gnome 42.3.
I can  run firefox and all other apps including thorium, the app image version of chrome. I forgot to run chromium. I'll do that tomorrow.
I did have chrome remote desktop installed. I  would see corruption/artifacts in the dock.
I captured an image of PS - aux. Then I ran killall chrome. This caused the artifacts to go away. I was able to boot X11 and remove chrome  remote  desktop. Now there are no artifacts and I am prompted for the ring password before I  get the white screen. Chrome runs just fine under x 11. I will post the captured image of the ps -aux results tomorrow. I will be running a fresh install of Ubuntu 24.04 very soon. I just want to find an answer to this before I do that since it seems to be relevant to Wayland development and maybe the rx6400 as well.

Sounds like a bug, either a packaging one or an upstream one, not exactly sure.

Can someone help me with a Todo list to collect data and report this properly?
